# how to set remember me option in laravel 5.4 using cookie

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

in controller

```
$cookie=Cookie('rem_username',$username,60);
$cookie1=Cookie('rem_password',$password,60);
    return redirect()->action("Logincheck@dashboardvalue")->cookie($cookie)->cookie($cookie1);
```

the cookies are set ,
how to use this in view page of login

Comment: I recommend using `$_SESSION` instead - easier to initialise and safer too. in the above example, for session, would be `$_SESSION['rem_username'] = $username`

Comment: session wiil be destroyed after user exit from the application

Comment: yeah exactly that's why it's safe haha

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cookie facade  or use cookie helper function

```
{{ Cookie::get('rem_username') }} OR 

{{ cookie('rem_username') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

May this also work for you:

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::get('rem_username')}}
```